# How to avoid accordion overlapping on footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to jQuery. I'm using Accordion. When I click on the accordion it overlaps on the footer. How can I avoid it

Below is the code for the footer -

```
<footer>
    <div class="row footer_class">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-lg-8 font_color">Copyright &#169; 2013</div>
            <div class="col-lg-2  pull-right font_color">Powered by Test</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

[image]Below is the picture of how accordion overlaps the footer.
 I don't want it to overlap the footer but the footer should move down below the accordion when the collapsible menu is opened.

Comment: We need to see the CSS for the footer.

Comment: it seems that your element is in absolute position. Does your HTML structure allows you to simply leave it in the flow as static position ? ... no code only gives you guess answers

Answer (score 0):

The problem is either the CSS for some wrapper for the accordions

Or the footer has been set to be fixed at that position on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Make the wrapper (e.g. div) for the accordion fluid such that when accordion expands the wrapper height extends as well. Or you may add a dummy div after the accordion wrapper which will change in height when accordion is opened thus pushing the footer down.

Answer (score 0):

set relative position for your footer.

`position:relative`

Happy Coding:)