# How to correct overlapping accordion on footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

I'm new to jQuery. I'm using Accordion. When I click on the accordion it overlaps on the footer. How can I avoid it

Below is the code for the footer -

```
<footer>
    <div class="row footer_class">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-lg-8 font_color">Copyright &#169; 2013</div>
            <div class="col-lg-2  pull-right font_color">Powered by Test</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Below is the picture of how accordion overlaps the footer.
[image]
 I don't want it to overlap the footer but the footer should move down below the accordion when the collapsible menu is opened.
Below is the CSS for the footer -

```
.row_color{
border:2px solid #A40F17;
margin:0px;
}
.footer_class{
background-color:#A40F17;
height:40px;
color:#fff;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
position : relative;
}
```

But still the footer overlaps over accordion

Comment: i believe its a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22424405/1328014

Comment: @JoeySalacHipolito I'm unable to delete that and I had not included css there

Answer (score 0):

You could try the CSS code `clear: both` either on the footer or the div that wraps your accordion.

Comment: No change witnessed. Still the same

Comment: What about adding `display: block;` both to the footer and the div that wraps your accordion?

Comment: Maybe you set any floating position inside the div that wraps the accordion. That would make the floating object overflow the div (divs do not expand when floating objects inside them move or grow).

Without any more code, I don't think I can help anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Surprised at the lack of answers to this question around stackoverflow. Anyone who finds themself in a similar situation, or has a better solution, please see answer here [Collapsible javascript element overlapping footer (not accordion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47145465/collapsible-javascript-element-overlapping-footer-not-accordion/65389466#65389466)