# bootstrap accordion dropdown behind footer

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

so my problem is when I expand my bootstrap accordion it does not push down the footer. Instead it just expands behind the footer.

my footer is not fixed, it has position relative.

here is the code for my footer.

```
  <div class="bottombg">
    <footer class="footer">

  <div class="col-sm-1"> </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="small_space"></div>
      <div class="">    
          <img src="images/logo.png" alt="..">  
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="small_space"></div>
    <p> Leceister | UK | England </p> 
    <p> &copy; 2014 the Regents of University of Leceister <br>
        University Road <br> Leicester <br>
        LE1 7RH <br> United Kingdom <br>
    </p>            
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <h3> Site Visitors </h3>
    <p> <a>Academic Departments</a> <br>
        <a>Accessibility <br> <a>Help</a> <br>
        <a>Job Opportunities <br> <a>Legal</a> <br> <a>Privacy &amp; Cookies</a> 
    </p>            
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <h3>  Staff &amp; Students  </h3>
    <p> <a>Blackboard</a> <br>
        <a>Current Students <br> <a> Remote Access</a> <br>
            <a> Staff</a> <br> 
    </p>            
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <h3> Social Media  </h3>
    <img src="images/icons/With%20Border/facebook-variation.png">
    <img src="images/icons/With%20Border/twitter-variation.png">
    <img src="images/icons/With%20Border/rss-variation.png">  
    <img src="images/icons/With%20Border/youtube-variation.png"> 
  </div>

</footer>
```

Here is my css for my footer

```
.footer {
  position: relative;
  height: 130px;
  padding-top:20px;
}
```

I have also found this post, but no luck [How to correct overlapping accordion on footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22428578/how-to-correct-overlapping-accordion-on-footer?lq=1)

Here are screen shots to help explain what my problem is.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/keAX2.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8iso.png

Comment: Put a clear:both on the .footer.

Comment: I tried that, didnt work =/

Comment: I'm guessing the drop down has absolute positioning? In that case, increase the z-index if that's all you need

Answer (score 0):

Its rather hard to see what eaxactly the problem is here unless you give all the code (link to the page maybe)... Try with using overflow:hidden for the footer or display:block.
Another thing i also would try is adding clear:both for the footer (not like its 100% sure to work). Usually this problem comes when you have strangly positioned elements (absolute, fixed e.t.c).

Clear:both - will clear the floats, so you dont need it i think.
Display:block - will make the element behave like block (go fullwidth and no elements before and after on the same line) - again, maybe not best

**The dropdown:** If you make it position:relative and add z-index bigger then the footer's it will overlap it. Then you can also set background:white so the text doesnt overlap.