# Collapsible javascript element overlapping footer (not accordion)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am not using "accordion" for these collapsible elements and hoping to avoid it as it would take a lot of time to convert to it I think. I have two elements that are expandable/collapsible and when I open the bottom-most one, it overlaps the footer. I have figured out how to make it a sticky footer so it sits at the bottom of the page now, but I can't seem to push it down any further if the content grows in height due to expansion of an element (if the footer isn't sticky, it works fine, but then the footer rests in the middle of the page which isn't wanted).

I've viewed a few threads on here about accordions overlapping footers but I've never seen any of them come up with a solution. Anybody have any suggestions?

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <div class="comm-container library-link-container">
            <p class="text-p1"><span id="library-plus-minus">+</span><a class="link" id="library-link"> NQSP</a></p>
            <div class="expand-collapse-container text-p2" id="library-explanation">
                <p class="text-p2">stuff</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="comm-container calendar-container">
            <p class="text-p1"><span id="calendar-plus-minus">+</span><a class="link" id="calendar-link"> Calendar</a></p>
            <div class="expand-collapse-container text-p2" id="calendar-explanation">
                <p class="text-p2">stuff</p>
                <div id="mobile-calendar"></div>
                <div id="desktop-calendar"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="push"></div>
        <div class="footer copyright-container">
            <p class="center">© <span id="copyright-year"></span> <span>NBCI</span> </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.comm-container{
    border-bottom: thick solid rgb(8,107,27);
    padding: 0 10%;
}

#desktop-calendar{
    display: block;
    padding: 1% 0 3% 0;
}

#mobile-calendar{
    display: none;
}

#wrapper{
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#content{
    height: 80vh;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.footer, #push{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var libraryLink = false;
    var calendarLink = false;
    var width = $(window).width();

    //First expandable-collapsible enabled here
    $("#library-link").click(function() {
        if (!libraryLink) {
            $("#library-explanation").css("max-height", "2000px");
            $("#library-plus-minus").html("-");
            libraryLink = true;
        } else {
            $("#library-explanation").css("max-height", "0");
            $("#library-plus-minus").html("+");
            libraryLink = false;
        }
    });

    //Creating calendar...
    $('#desktop-calendar').fullCalendar({
        //whole lot of code here to set up the calendar views
    });

    //second expandable-collapsible enabled here
    $("#calendar-link").click(function() {
        if (!calendarLink) {
            $("#calendar-explanation").css("max-height", "2000px");
            $("#calendar-plus-minus").html("-");
            $('#desktop-calendar').show();
            calendarLink = true;
        } else {
            $("#calendar-explanation").css("max-height", "0");
            $("#calendar-plus-minus").html("+");
            $('#desktop-calendar').hide();
            calendarLink = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can't you just switch a class on click and do the rest using CSS?

Comment: @Kontsnor Could you give me an example? I'm not well-versed in Javascript, the stuff you see above I have cobbled together by mimicry of documentation and other resources. What would the new class have to look like to get the footer to move down when the element is expanded?

Comment: I meant CSS classes. Like add a class `hidden` and `showing` for example. Add the plus/minus sign using CSS ::after selector, also add the max-height in the CSS. That way you only need too call toggleClass in javascript.

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle for live demo.. try setting z-index to 0 for your divs..

Comment: @Kontsnor Thanks for the tips, your suggestion sent me in the right direction. Creating those CSS classes would make my javascript look a lot cleaner, but the problem wouldn't have been solved as the problem was with how the footer acted upon click since I needed it to move down upon expansion of an element. By using toggleClass though I was able to change how the footer acted upon clicking by removing the "footer" class where the position was set to absolute. When it's not absolutely positioned, it recognizes the expansion of an element and moves down the page as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Questions a bit old but I was trying to figure this one out and couldn't find any answers, so here's how I did it with jQuery.

```
$('.last-list-item').click(function() {
    $(".footer").toggleClass('mt-max');
 });
```

So just to explain the code a bit. I'm using bulma css framework which I've customized a bit, so the mt-max class adds 100px margin to the top of any element it applies to. But you can easily create your own css class with the desired margin.

1. Create a class in your CSS file that adds x margin-top

```
.add-top-margin {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

2. Add click event listener to collapsible container (you may need to add a unique ID to any you want to target)

```
$('#collapsibleContainer').click(function() {
   // target footer here
});
```

3. Use toggleClass to add and remove our newly created class to the footer on clicking the accordion.

```
$('.my-footer').toggleClass('add-top-margin');
```

So in the end, you should have this in your jquery file

```
$('#collapsibleContainer').click(function() {
   $('.my-footer').toggleClass('add-top-margin');
});
```

You can tweak this however you like, you can choose to add padding to the accordion or whatever suits you best, but you get the idea.

*Edit
I changed my style to add padding to the bottom of the section that was encapsulating my accordion rather than adding top margin to the footer. This was because using margin added some white space and the section background is teal.